# Does the new location have to be zero for the loop to end in brainf*uck

Tags: loops, brainfuck

I was wondering abt bf loops then it just got much more complicated.
when you open the loop(`[`) at the pointer location 0, then go forward(`>`) in the loop(`[>`). Does the new location have to be zero for the loop to end?
...as the loop will only run then the cell value is equal to zero

so a little help on how brainf*ck loops work

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the loop "[>]". If the pointer points to a 0 when the '[' is first executed, then the loop will be skipped entirely and the pointer won't move. Whereas if it points to a nonzero, it will execute the loop and move the pointer right, and then if that cell is nonzero it will execute again and move the pointer right again, and it will keep moving the pointer right until it gets to a cell that's 0.